# Materializecss: how to make image cover full width within grid

Tags: css, materialize

i am new to css and try using materialize. i create row with 2 columns. the left coloumn is for image, the right coloumn is for the text. this is my html structure

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l8">
         <img src="imgae_url_here.jpg" alt="" class="responsive-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m12 l4 headline-right">
        <p class="category">CHROMECAST</p>
        <h2 class="feat-article-title">Here’s to five years of Chromecast</h2>
        <p class="feat-article-summary">Lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet...</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn grey lighten-4 grey-text text-darken-3 z-depth-1 waves-effect btn-headline">READ ARTICLE<i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i> </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the image is not have same width with row as shown bellow.

[image]

How to make the image full width same as row? the yellow line in the image shown above is what i want covered with that image. how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: could you once show full image with text ?

Comment: it is image. the text on the image is not text.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VTNax/2542/ check this out ? do you want something like that?

Comment: just like this https://blog.google/ the headline section. any suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
    <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l8" style="overflow:hidden">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1080/480/any" style="margin-left:-12px">
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m12 l4 headline-right">
        <p class="category">CHROMECAST</p>
        <h2 class="feat-article-title">Here’s to five years of Chromecast</h2>
        <p class="feat-article-summary">Lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet lorem ipsum doler sit amet...</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn grey lighten-4 grey-text text-darken-3 z-depth-1 waves-effect btn-headline">READ ARTICLE<i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i> </a>
      </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

here is your requested answer. Hope this will help :) Revert me back for any problem or queries

Comment: happy to help :)